# Closed embedding of topological groups and representation category

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, monoidal-categories

If $\mathcal{T}_1,\mathcal{T}_2$ are two neutral Tannakian categories with fibre functors $\omega_1,\omega_2$ respectively. Then a morphism of neutral Tannakian categories
$$F:\mathcal{T}_1\to \mathcal{T}_2$$
compatible with the fibre functors yields a morphism of fundamental groups schemes
$$f:\pi^{\omega_2}(\mathcal{T}_2)\to \pi^{\omega_1}(\mathcal{T}_1).$$
Then $f$ is a closed immersion if and only if every element of $\mathcal{T}_2$ is a subquotient element of the essential image of $F$.

My question is if a simliar statement holds for the categories of continous, finite dimensional complex representations of compact groups? That is, if $G_1,G_2$ are compact groups, and a nice functor
$$F:\text{Rep}_{\mathbb{C}}^{fd, cts}(G_2)\to \text{Rep}_{\mathbb{C}}^{fd, cts}(G_1)$$
yields a morphism of topological groups $f:G_1\to G_2$ such that $f$ is a closed embedding if and only if every element of $\mathcal{T}_2$ is a subquotient element of the essential image of $F$?